# Selenium IDE: how to remove \n from stored string?

Tags: string, selenium, ide

I am trying to extract the zip code from an address string but it contains newline \n characters.  May I ask how to remove it from a selenium stored var?  I have tried to use `storeEval | "${Addrsss}".replace("\n", "") | Address`.  But, selenium ide will return the error `Threw an exception: unterminated string literal`

Here is the address:
`${Address} = "100 RILEY DR\n AVONDALE,\n ARIZONA\n 85323-2004"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this sequence of escape>replace>unescape as a workaround to remove the new line character:

1. Escape the value,
2. Replace the escaped new line character (`%0A`) with blank (''),
3. Unescape back to the original value,

```
storeEval | unescape(escape(storedVars['has_nl']).replace(/%0A/g,'')) | no_nl
```

This new line character appears to have come from HTML break tag (`<br />`) that is rendered by the browser-Selenium-IDE combination, then extracted by Selenium IDE as new line character (`\\n`).

Comment: this worked for me excellently, just in replace I have as an secon argument a comma space `.replace(/%0A/g,', ')`

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:
1) find proper css (or xPath) locator of the element  (address)
2) then get contents ( text) from element using

```
String cssSelecotr=..blablabla..
//1st way
String myAddress=driver.findELement(by.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText();
//2nd way, using js executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSelecotr+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String myAddress= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

3) then you can apply regExp ( all visible symbols) for yourAdress

```
 //  myAddress ="100 RILEY DR\n AVONDALE,\n ARIZONA\n 85323-2004";

         String myAdressEdited = myAddress.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7E]+","");
```

Hope this helps